# Grunt with Uglify same src and dest directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am starting to use Grunt with the Uglify plugin to minify my JS and CSS files. We are utilizing Grunt on our server that hosts these files.

Is it possible to have Grunt-uglify utilize the same folder the *.js files are in and keep the file names? I have it now minifying the files into a separate directory and it's working fine. However, we develop locally and point all of our scripts to the normal .js files. This same code gets pushed to the production server. We would either need to keep the minified files in the same directory and just minified, or when Grunt-uglify minimizes into another directory, we'll have to change our script code upon deployment to point to these new files.

My gruntfile.js file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            js: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: 'dest/js',
            cwd: 'js/'
                }]
            },
        options: {
            mangle: false,
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify:js']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting the src and dest to the same directory and it works. The files get over written. I know this isn't best practice, but it's how we need it to work for the time being.